# Python comprehension and data structures

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm learning some python, and I have the following program:

```
sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
words = sentence.split()

print "\n What the hell is this???"
word_lengths = [(word, len(word)) for word in words if word != "the".lower()]
print word_lengths

What the hell is this???
[('quick', 5), ('brown', 5), ('fox', 3), ('jumps', 5), ('over', 4), ('lazy', 4), ('dog', 3)]
```

I don't understand the strange list that i get with the latter block o code..

What kind of structure is it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a list of tuples. What's the problem?

Comment: You can read about tuples and sequences [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: Thank you all, that's what i needed!

Comment: Pretty long code for a short question.

Answer (score 2):

It is a list of tuples. A tuple is simply an immutable list, in the form `x, y, z` or `(x, y, z)`

When you call this code:

```
word_lengths = [(word, len(word)) for word in words if word != "the".lower()]
```

You ask Python to fabricate a list [a, b] containing tuples (x, y) with x being the word and y being the length of the word.

It is semantically almost equivalent to:

```
word_lengths = [[word, len(word)] for word in words if word != "the".lower()]
```

With the only exception that you cannot modify the tuple once created.

Note: to create a tuple of 1 element, you need to add a comma to distinguish with an expression between parentheses:  `(a,)`